# Ant get task - save file as its given name

Tags: ant

I am using Ant's "get" task to save a file to disk. I am not very familiar with Ant and can't figure out how to strip the filename from the source url to use as the file's destination.

Example:

```
<property name="srcUrl" value="http://localhost/foo/bar.html" />
<property name="destLocation" value="" />
....
<!-- now, dynamically grab "bar.html" from srcUrl and store it in destLocation -->
<get src="${srcUrl}" dest="${destLocation}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<basename property="destLocation" file="${srcUrl}"/>
```